# Is there a way to add line breaks in a string of text in Microsoft's DAX language?

Tags: line-breaks, dax, powerbi

I have a DAX function that pulls in multiple strings of text (from multiple columns) into one cell. But on display I want to have a line break in between the header and the body of the paragraph. Is there a way to code in a line break with DAX? FYI, I'm using Power BI for this. Thanks!

Comment: The usual "suspects" \n\r and <br /> just gave me "\n\r and <br />" respectively in the text field....

Comment: Can you use power Query to importa data? if you can do this i have used a solution time ago to insert carriage return between string. let me know

Comment: You can use power query to import data, but I'm looking to create a new carriage return and don't know the code to do so...

Answer (score 12):

Using DAX
String = [field A] **& UNICHAR(10) &** [field B]

Example:
 Field A contains text: January 11, 2018
 Field B contains text: Happy Birthday Elvis

This will return:

January 11, 2018

Happy Birthday Elvis

Answer (score 10):

In BI Desktop, just type alt-enter in your DAX formula to add new line
For example:

```
CONCATENATEX(Project, ProjectName & ":" & [some-measure], 
//new line in parameter delimiter
",
"
)
```

Comment: This is a good solution for this, but using Variables is recommended in the DAX Formula as it can be used multiple time. Find an example here:
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/how-to-get-text-in-new-line-in-the-data-cards-label/m-p/441556/highlight/true#M203915

Answer (score 2):

First, we have to create string concatenation using **CONCATENATE()** method, then use **UNICHAR(10)** to create space between strings

```
Product Sold Count =

VAR Valuel = "Product Sold" 

VAR Value2 = "Today : " & (
                            CALCULATE(
                                SUMX(
                                    FILTER(
                                            'api_Product Sold',
                                            'api_Product Sold'[Date] = TODAY()
                                        ),
                                    'api_Product Sold'[Count]
                                    )
                                )
                        + 0 ) 

VAR Value3 = "Total : " & (
                            CALCULATE(
                                SUMX(
                                    FILTER(
                                            'api_Product Sold',
                                            'api_Product Sold'[Date] <= TODAY()
                                        ),
                                    'api_Product Sold'[Count]
                                    )
                                )
                        + 0 )  

VAR FirstCONCATENATE = CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(Valuel,UNICHAR(10)),Value2) 

VAR SecondCONCATENATE = CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE(Value2,UNICHAR(10)),Value3) 

RETURN SecondCONCATENATE
```

Once your string is ready then select card chat and assign the measure created

[image]

Where height of the card chart should be proper then only word wrap will work and before it should be enable the word wrap property on format tab

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The PowerqueryFormulaReference uses in the Lines.ToText example something like 
`#(cr)#(lf)`
I added this as a string (!) to my text and it worked...

Comment: I hate to split hairs (especially in a discussion about concatenation:-) ) but PowerQuery is not DAX. The question seems to be specifically about DAX.

Answer (score -4):

The one that worked for me is `<br/>`.

Do something like this:

```
String = CONCATENATE(CONCATENATE("HEADER","<br/>"),"BODY")
```

The espected output is:

HEADER
BODY

Comment: All I'm getting from this is:
HEADER<br/>BODY